# ActionLink for a Custom MapRoute with two URL Parameters

Tags: actionlink, url-parameters

I have a custom MapRoute

```
context.MapRoute("participantByGender",
"Admin/Participants/{id}/{gender}",
new {
    controller = "Admin",
    action = "Participants",
    id = UrlParameter.Optional,
    gender = UrlParameter.Optional
}
```

and i need to have a link which specifies both the id and a default gender. I have this one, which works for choosing the id, but how would i alter this to include the id and the gender in the link?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Participants", "Participants", new { id = item.termId })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply use:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Participants", "Participants", new { id = item.termId,gender=model.property })
```

Comment: Thank you for that, I see that it works. However, is the fact that the url is "/Admin/Participants/1205B?gender=male" and the maproute outlines it as "Admin/Participants/{id}/{gender}" going to create problems in the future? should i update the maproute to be "Admin/Participants/{id}?gender={gender}"?

Comment: @user1902060:I will suggest you to keep your url as you are getting it currently...can't say for any reason but this is how they do it...